# NWJS - Is it possible to intercept loading of JS from a remote page, and inject my own?

Tags: nwjs

I am trying to debug an issue with an NWJS app I have made, which loads a web page from a surveillance camera on my network into an iframe.

Is there a way I can intercept the loading of the javascript files, allowing me to inject my own JS for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

When opening a new window, you can use `inject_js_start` or `inject_js_end`. Which, if you just need this for debugging, that will likely be the easiest approach.

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowopenurl-options-callback

```js
nw.Window.open('https://example.com', { inject_js_start: 'file.js' });
```

For an iframe, I'm not sure if there is a similar feature. There is `postMessage` for communicating with an iframe.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

There is also `webview` which is a special type of iframe that some use in NW.js:

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/#webview-tag

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to inject the js, however it does not appear to inhibit the js loading from the source.

Comment: Correct, you can run you JS first, or last.

Comment: Okay, so I assume your point is, if I run mine last, I can override objects/methods that have been loaded from the source.

Comment: In a lot of cases, that may work, however, if the source JS has self-executing anonymous functions, they can't be overriden.